# I am having troubles with changing image every few seconds while also scaling the image responsively at 100% height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, jsfiddle

I am having troubles with changing image every few seconds while also scaling the image responsively at 100% height and width. I cant get it to scale while keeping the proportions.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wez07qn/3/#&togetherjs=TlopaRQOy7

Click the link above to join me to find the solution to my question. It is really complex and when i previously explained my question, confusion and long answers followed. I will be in the collaboration fiddle.

My code
HTML

```
<div class="Wrapper2">
  <div id="HomeRooms"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#HomeRooms {
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#HomeRooms img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.Wrapper2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){

var picCount=0;  
var picArray= ["http://bit.ly/1uxYSSb","http://bit.ly/1oOrsO6"];

    nextPic();

 function nextPic()
  {  picCount=(picCount+1<picArray.length)? picCount+1 : 0;
     var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[picCount]+
     '" style="" />';
     document.getElementById("HomeRooms").innerHTML=build;
   setTimeout(function(){nextPic();},6000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Use the images as background images to a div, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: When you give a CSS `width` to an `img` tag, without giving it an explicit height, it scales proportionately just fine. I was able to reproduce this by changing `max-width` to `width` in your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wez07qn/4/).

Comment: Also, your code is more complex than it needs to be. Just update your `img`’s `src` instead of creating new HTML and `function(){nextPic();}` can be replaced with just `nextPic`.

Comment: I did that, but the images cannot be seen in my file. I changed the img urls to my files but the images doesnt show up. I cant see them

Answer (score 0):

To get the best result, use a background image and background-size: cover.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/dq01wsou/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="HomeRooms"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#HomeRooms {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function(){

var picCount=0;  
var picArray= ["http://bit.ly/1uxYSSb","http://bit.ly/1oOrsO6"];
nextPic();

function nextPic() { 
   picCount=(picCount+1<picArray.length) ? picCount+1 : 0;
   $("#HomeRooms").css('backgroundImage', 'url('+picArray[picCount]+')');
   setTimeout(function() {
       nextPic();},6000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what i want. But when i integrate that exact same code to my project, the images are not visible.

Comment: If there are no errors, can you open the dev tools and inspect the computed styles for the HomeRoom div and see if the background image is there and if so, is the url correct.  That would be my first steps in debugging.